# Best practice for changing a service response? (XML)

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd

I'm maintaining a .NET web service from which the users will receive an XML-file containing any errors found in their imported XML.

The problem is that the returned XML claims to conform to an xsd which it in fact does not. I would now like to create a brand new xsd thus completely redesigning the returned XML. This would however create a problem for users who have built their own custom error handling based on the currently returned XML.

Are there any best practices when it comes to completely redesign the response of a web service that I should try to implement? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too vague and broad. Why does the returned XML claim to conform to this XSD if in fact it does not? If you cannot change the returned XML because of your users, then why not change the XSD only?

Comment: The XSD is the same one as is used to validate the imported files. Our returned XML claims to be using that XSD but is not designed as such. This is something that was done way before I started maintaining the service and there's a possibility that some of our current users need the XML to look like it currently does.